# How to write each new mail to a separate file using tail -f?

Tags: email, tail

I am monitoring the mail file for new emails. The goal is to create a new file for each new email that reaches localhost.

This is what I have so far.

```
current="$(date +"%Y_%m_%d_%I_%M_%p").txt"
tail -f /var/spool/mail/root > $current
```

The problem is that a new file is not created for each new mail. Any suggestions?

Comment: Don't use tail or just split by a certain line. Alternatively just change to [maildir](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maildir) instead of mbox. It's pretty vague what your goal is. Using a [mail](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/239380/use-mail-to-read-email-from-command-line) client might be easier depending on it.

Comment: @Seth The goal is to write each new mail as a file in a directory. That's about it. I have other scripts monitoring this directory.

Comment: So change it to maildir it have it out of the box?

Answer (score 1):

Your mail spool contains Berkeley `mbox` format. Any line which starts with the five characters `From`(space) is a separator which starts a new message.

A shell loop on its own cannot decide on the fly where to redirect stuff, but something like this should work:

```
tail -f "$MAIL" |
awk 'BEGIN { n=0; where="/dev/null" }
    /^From / { close(where); where=sprintf("./message-%07s", ++n) }
    { print >>where }'
```

We start by writing to `/dev/null` in case `tail` starts reading in the middle of a message. Now each time we see a new message separator, we update `n` and `where`. The last line prints every line to wherever `where` points.

It needs to be said that this is not a good way to handle your mail spool. For one thing, anything between `tail` invocations will be lost; and `tail` won't cope if something truncates the mail spool file. Perhaps you'd want to look at Procmail or Maildrop instead.